# How to intersect to array in D?

Tags: arrays, d

I need to find difference between two arrays of strings in D. The problem, that I can't understand how to use `SetDifference` from `std.algorithm`.

```
    auto x = SetDifference(filearr1,filearr2);
```

get error:

`Error: struct std.algorithm.SetDifference cannot deduce function from argument types !()(string[], string[]), candidates are:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setDifference` with a lower-case "s".

`SetDifference` is the name of the type that's returned by `setDifference`, which happens to be a template struct. The compiler cannot automatically determine template arguments from structs, only from function calls, which is why for most of those template structs a helper function exists.